# How to programatically invoke the functions available on browser Add-on

Tags: java, firefox-addon, toolbar, ui-automation, browser-automation

One of client requires a add-on to be installed for a browser and perform all the available functions of that add-on from the add-on bar. The add-on has been coded in Javascript and there are many options available on that add-on. Let's say if there are option A, option B, option C and option D as 4 menu items on add-on which are intended for a specific purpose,

As part of testing the add-on behavior, how is it possible to invoke/click the options on add-on from the add-on bar of the browser, which inturn would invoke the javascript function.

Your advice and help will be deeply appreciated.